# Series convergence of $\frac{(-1)^n}{x^{2n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Does this series converge, and if so how would I prove it? I thought of using the ratio test but I'm not sure.
The series is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{x^{2n+1}}.
$$

Comment: What kind of tests you have known?

Comment: Depends on the value of $x$

Comment: You should be able to tell the series converges without summing it.

Answer (score 4):

Provided that $|x|>1$, the series converges. Note that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{x^{2n+1}}=\frac1x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{-1}{x^2}\right)^n=\frac1x\frac1{1+\frac1{x^2}}=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$